# Google dialog flow REST API timeout

Tags: rest, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can I integrate my custom REST API with google dialog flow. 
If yes, then what is the timeout to set at google dialog flow. My API takes between 20-30 seconds to come back. Is there a flexibility in the chatbot to increase its timeout?

Comment: It seems to be 10 seconds based on personal testing. I can't find any way to increase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Assistant timeout after 10 sec, and Dialgflow service (for other platforms) timeout after 5 sec. Try to do some caching or improve service response time!

Comment: Thanks but API improvement is out of the scope, these are 3rd party api's. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: yeah I am also facing similar issue :(